# Popup triggers class ui-popup-hidden endlessly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm experiencing an issue with the jQuery Mobile Popup triggering itself to hide/unhide itself once opened continuously. It has quite an affect on the CPU. The popup text content is being added dynamically.

To replicate issue visit the following link then click:

1. Search Intervention
2. Select any one from listview you like
3. Select any one from listview you like
4. Click info button on the top right to show popup

(Link removed)

Has anyone had a similar issue with JQM Popups?

Comment: Okay. What would you like us to do about it?

Comment: alla kazam - i just magically read your screen, debugged your code and found the problem - you have missed a semi-colon at the end of a line, insert this and your problem will disappear entirely

Comment: Sorry last part of post was lost - (edited see above)

Comment: Please add code, not a link to your website. It's possible that you have _multiplied_ bindings/listeners. How do you call the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem - it was due to another plugin running on a set timeout that conflicted with this.